React/Next.js automatic open app scheme url not working
I want to open our app scheme when the page is done loading. When pressing the button the url opens in the app. So I thought that by putting calling openApp from the useEffect the app would automatically open when the page is done loading. On desktop a new tab is opened with the composed url, but on mobile (Safari iOS) it is not. Am i doing something wrong?
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import AppStoreEmbeds from '../../components/AppStoreEmbeds'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Index() {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('open app');
    setTimeout(() => {
      openApp();
    }, 500);
  }, [])

  const openApp = () => {
    const path = window.location.href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')
    const appUrl = `myapp:/${path}`;
    console.log('appUrl', appUrl);
    window.open(appUrl);
  }

  return <Layout>
    <div className='max-w-md mb-10 p-5 pt-0 mt-20 pl-10 pr-10'>

        
        <div className='flex justify-items-center justify-center flex-col items-center mb-20 pb-20'>
          
          <button onClick={() => {
            openApp();
          }} type="button" className='bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold text-xl p-8 pt-4 pb-4 rounded-lg right flex gap-2 items-center'>
            Open in Momo
          </button> 

        </div>

        
        <AppStoreEmbeds />
        
    </div>
  </Layout>
}

